# Удаленный деструктор

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, деструктор

Читаю "A Tour of C++" Страуструпа, и наталкиваюсь на стр. 77 на такой совет:

> If a class has a pointer member, it probably needs a user-defined or deleted destructor, copy and move.

Т.е. вроде бы как

> Если класс имеет член-указатель, вероятно, ему требуются пользовательские или удаленные деструктор, копирование и перемещение.

Про копирование и перемещение - нет вопросов, все понятно, про пользовательский деструктор - тоже.

Но что может означать удаленный деструктор? Не в плане написать

```
~Class() = delete;
```

а что это может дать? Ведь такой объект нельзя будет удалить ни автоматом по выходу из области видимости, ни через `delete` (понятно, локальный и выделенный через `new` соответственно).

В чем тут глубокий смысл - создавать бессмертные объекты? :)

P.S. Написал Страуструпу, потребовал объяснений :) Он согласился, что формулировка не самая точная, предложил вариант

> If a class has a pointer member, consider if it needs a user-defined or deleted destructor, copy and move;

Как по мне, разница невелика, но тем не менее... В этом плане ответ @lёxölüt ближе к реалиям, потому принимаю именно его.

Comment: Можно использовать бессмертный объект синглетон, живущий все время работы приложения. Вещь не особо нужная, но синтаксически и семантически допустимая.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смысл вытекает из Правила трёх (пяти). И читать это следует группами ***(user-defined or deleted)*** и ***(destructor, copy and move)***. Т.е. любую из упомянутых функций следует либо сделать определённой пользователем, либо удалённой.

Акцент на удалённом деструкторе получается, видимо, из-за расположения этих слов рядом. То, что этот случай несколько более особенный, чем для копирования/перемещения, можно было бы отразить в исходном предложении, но тогда оно стало бы более многословным. А к чему это ведёт для объекта уже сказано в смежном ответе, да и в самом вопросе, по сути, тоже.

Стоит заметить, что при создании объекта в куче (на стеке не получится, т.к. реализация сама вставляет вызов деструктора в код), тем не менее можно избежать сомнительных утечек, достаточно использовать глобальные операторы `new`/`delete` и размещающий `new`:

```
#include <new>

struct S {
    ~S() = delete;
};

int main()
{
    void* p = ::operator new (sizeof(S)); // Выделили память
    S* s = new (p) S; // Сконструировали объект по адресу 'p'
    ::operator delete(p); // Освободили память
}
```

Comment: Т.е. меня подвело знание английского? :)

Comment: @Harry удаление деструктора формально разрешено. То, что этот случай несколько более особенный, чем для копирования/перемещения, можно было бы отразить в исходном предложении, но тогда оно стало бы более многословным. По сути, возможность удаления деструктора - это более сильный способ закрыть возможность создания на стеке. До с++11 это достигалось размещением деструктора в приватной секции.

Comment: @älёxölüt, но Вы же понимаете, что Страуструп не имел в виду подобных извращений?

Comment: Потому я и написал в комменте подробнее, почему фраза построена именно так. Добавил в текст ответа на всякий случай.

Comment: См. P.S. к вопросу...

Comment: @Harry автограф взяли? :)

Comment: @älёxölüt Ну, если б я ему слал бумажной почтой, то, может, и автограф был бы :) А так - разве что типа *dkim=pass header.i=@stroustrup-com.20150623.gappssmtp.com header.s=20150623 header.b=qSNNiln8;* :)

Answer (score 4):

Единственная причина для объявления класса с удаленным деструктором, которая приходит в голову: такие объекты нельзя будет объявлять, как автоматические или статические, нельзя будет использовать в качестве подобъектов, но можно будет создавать в динамической памяти, при условии, что они не будут освобождаться, т.е. будут сознательно отправляться в memory leaks.

В чем, однако, связь с темой менеджмента ресурсов через голый указатель - не ясно. Возможно, просто непродуманная формулировка.

Comment: Ну, вот я тоже подумал, что тут что-то Страуструп не так сформулировал :) Рядом у него, кстати, тоже формулировка еще та: "If a class has a destructor, it probably needs user-defined or deleted copy and move" - я бы сказал, что *user-defined destructor*...

Comment: Кстати, чтоб перекрыть возможность объявления как статического или автоматического - вроде бы достаточно деструктор сделать `private`, нет?

Comment: а не лучше делать deleted?

Comment: @KoVadim Не думаю. Тогда динамический объект - бессмертен, а так - его можно удалить, пусть и не через delete непосредственно.

Comment: а, да, через свой "спецдеструктор".

Comment: @Harry, да там банально destructor попал в список, где его не должно быть. Нет там никакого глубинного смысла.

Comment: Связь очевидна: если там старый добрый пойнтер, деструктор по умолчанию ничего с ним не сделает, и если это приватный объект, он утекает.

Comment: См. P.S. к вопросу...